# Getting default value of the default drop down list choice on Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set a SQL parameter via the default value of a DropDownMenu:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["userParam"].DefaultValue = nameDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I presume this is because there is no selected value yet. I tried:

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["userParam"].DefaultValue = nameDropDownList.Items[1].Value;
```

and

```
nameDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["userParam"].DefaultValue = nameDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

Is there a way to get the value of a drop down list on page load?

Comment: Are you sure the object "SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["userParam"]" is not null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from ta where name like '%'+@userParam+'%'";
if (SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Count == 0)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("userParam", DbType.String, nameDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
}
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["userParam"].DefaultValue = nameDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value ;
```